# Spark DataFrame - Applying Schema shows nullable always true

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to apply a schema for one of my json file. And does not matter if I provide nullable for this particular filed `true` or `false` in schema, when I apply that schema on my file, the field comes as `nullable` only.

**Schema**

```
val schema = StructType(
    List(
        StructField("SMS", StringType, false)
     )
)
```

**output**

```
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(SMS,StringType,false))
```

**applying Schema on file**

val SMSDF = spark.read.schema(schema).json("/mnt/aaa/log*")
SMSDF.printSchema()

**output**

```
 root
 |-- SMS: string (nullable = true)
```

**I am using Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11**